# infrastructure for aggregating data periodically and serving it using node.js

Tags: javascript, json, database, node.js, aggregation

I'm interested in using Node.js to aggregate various pieces of information from different servers using JSON API's. Summarize it and serving it as static web pages. The data I am collecting is ~100kbytes so I am assuming it would reside in the memory and be served when request.

So is there a way of aggregating caching data in memory as a JSON structure which could be served to static pages. I would prefer not to write it in MongoDB.

I am using 'serve-static' to serve static web pages from node.js.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: oh yes - I would like to know what would be the best way to to achieve this ? will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The npm site shows [241 results for cron.](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=cron). Another approach would be to remember the last time you did an update, and, everytime a user connects, check that time and do a "just in time" update.  I have a site that does the latter.  Depends on how long and complex is the update.

It seems to me that using a templating engine like JADE would be superior to serving static pages that aren't really static.  Not that I like JADE, I don't, YMMV, but if your data is dynamic then using templates seems to make way more sense.

Storing JSON in memory or in Mongo is so simple that I really don't understand that part of your question.